# Set language for a panel page

Tags: 7, panels, i18n-l10n

How do I create multiple translations of a panel page?  My homepage is designed with panels and I have both english and spanish content.  For nodes everything is fine but I can't figure out how to do the multiple language thing with panels.

Comment: I have the same problem and I just noticed there's a module called Multilingual Panels: https://drupal.org/project/mlpanels Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't attempted this myself, but I would assume you can pass the current selected language in as a context and then trigger different variants of the panel based on that.

You could then also trigger individual pane visibility based on the current language (i.e don't show this untranslated pane to German visitors).

Comment: So now that I have done this it appears there isn't a panel-wide context. But the visibility rules per pane are in there and should solve most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but support for language context in Page manager is still in the works, and there is a debate about how it should work. Because the functionality may yet change, I'm not posting a todo, but just link to [the issue](http://drupal.org/node/1301908).